# Create a folder with special characters in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, special-characters, mkdir

I'm trying to create a folder in Python with `os.mkdir`, but I haven't been very successful. The thing is that I want to go through a list first, and for every item in that list I have to create a folder with that specific name. The list sometimes contains special characters like `ä, ü, ë` and so on in unicode.

This is what I have now:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

data_dir = "C:\Test"
lst = ["Geb\u00e4ude"]

for i in lst:
    print i
    i = i.decode('unicode_escape').encode("utf8")
    print i

    os.mkdir(os.path.join(data_dir, i))
```

The first time I print `i` i obviously get `Geb\u00e4ude`, the second time I get `Gebäude` after all the decoding and encoding. So far so good.

The thing is that I want now to create a folder in `data_dir` called `Gebäude`, but after calling `mkdir` I get a folder with other strange characters like `GebÃ¤ude` or something like that. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: When I run the code, nothing is printed. It seems to be due to the `reload(sys)` line, although I don't know why.

Comment: @Jachdich Actually you can comment `reload(sys)` and `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')` out, it doesn't make any difference in this case

Comment: ok (char lower limit is annoying)

Comment: does the special char have to be given in the form `\u00e4`, or can it be just `ä` in a string?

Comment: @Jachdich Sadly it is given that way :(

Comment: I posted an answer, I hope it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem:

`i = i.decode('unicode_escape').encode("utf8")`

It should be `i = i.decode('unicode_escape')`

That makes a folder called `Gebäude`

Comment: Oh christ, such a small thing. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Python 3:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
os.mkdir('Gebäude')
```

Python 2.7:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
os.mkdir(u'Gebäude')
```

At least this works on macOS, I hope it helps.

Comment: That could work, but how would I get the variable `i` inside the `os.mkdir(u'')`?

Comment: Can't you specify the string as unicode in the first place? i.e. when you create your `lst` list.

Comment: no, EvilHappyHippo stated that the chars were given in the form `\u00e4`